# Get Javadoc As Text

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

Eclipse just blew my mind again: there seems to be no easily accessible way to copy text or html out of the Javadoc previews. I've just written a substantial piece in Javadoc, assuming that I would be able to just select and copy the selection. I can select, but not copy.

Am I mistaken? If I am not, what's the easiest way to get the rendered text or html for one Javadoc comment?

Comment: How would 'Before' work? A command that copies the Javadoc html/text straight into the clipboard buffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag-and-drop seems to work. (Found a few minutes after I submitted the Q.)